# What's wrong with this Haskell AES key expansion?

Tags: haskell, aes, rijndael

Following steps describing key expansion in [Jeff Moser's popular tutorial](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html), I've written this code for key expansion. Here is the entire file (which also computes the S-Box), so folks can compile and try it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.Bits (xor, shiftL, shiftR, (.|.), (.&.))
import Data.List (transpose, sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Numeric (showHex)

keys = f 16 $ f 8 $ f 4 $ f 2 $ f 1 key
 where
  f w n = xpndC . xpndB . xpndA $ xpndD w n

xpndC   :: [[Word8]] -> [[Word8]]
xpndC ws = transpose [head ws, b, zipWith xor b c, last ws]
 where
  (b,c) = (ws !! 1, ws !! 2)

xpndB   :: [[Word8]] -> [[Word8]]
xpndB ws = a : zipWith xor a b : drop 2 ws
 where
  (a,b) = (head ws, ws !! 1)

xpndA   :: [[Word8]] -> [[Word8]]
xpndA ws = zipWith xor a d : tail ws
 where
  (a,d) = (head ws, last ws)

xpndD rc ws = take 3 tW ++ [w']
 where
  w' = zipWith xor (map sub w) [rc, 0, 0, 0]
  tW = transpose ws
  w  = take 4 $ tail $ cycle $ last tW

--------------------------------------------------------------
sub w = get sbox (fromIntegral lo) $ fromIntegral hi
 where
  (hi, lo) = nibs w

get wss x y = (wss !! y) !! x

print' = print . w128 . concat . transpose
 where
  w128 = concatMap (f . (`showHex` ""))
  f w  = (length w < 2) ? (' ':'0':w, ' ':w)

grid _ [] = []
grid n xs = take n xs : grid n (drop n xs)

nibs w    = (shiftR (w .&. 0xF0) 4, w .&. 0x0F)
(⊕)       = xor
p ? (a,b) = if p then a else b; infix 2 ?

---------------------------------------------------
sbox :: [[Word8]]
sbox = grid 16 $ map snd $ sortBy (comparing fst) $ sbx 1 1 []

sbx :: Word8 -> Word8 -> [(Word8, Word8)] -> [(Word8, Word8)]
sbx p q ws
  | length ws == 255 = (0, 0x63) : ws
  | otherwise = sbx p' r $ (p', xf ⊕ 0x63) : ws
 where
  p' = p  ⊕  shiftL p  1 ⊕  ((p .&. 0x80 /= 0) ? (0x1B, 0))
  q1 = foldl (liftA2 (.) xor shiftL) q [1, 2, 4]
  r  = q1 ⊕  ((q1 .&. 0x80 /= 0) ? (0x09, 0))
  xf = r  ⊕  rotl8 r 1 ⊕  rotl8 r 2 ⊕  rotl8 r 3 ⊕  rotl8 r 4

rotl8 w n = (w `shiftL` n) .|. (w `shiftR` (8 - n))

key = [[0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0],
       [0,0,0,0]] :: [[Word8]]
```

When I test this code against the all-zero test key, it matches the published expectation up to the fourth iteration: `ee 06 da 7b 87 6a 15 81 75 9e 42 b2 7e 91 ee 2b`.

But when I try the next iteration: `keys = f 16 $ f 8 $ f 4 $ f 2 $ f 1`, 
the last 32 bits of the result are wrong: `7f 2e 2b 88 f8 44 3e 09 8d da 7c bb 91 28 f1 f3`.

The same behavior - last 32 bits wrong - happens when I use all 0xFF for the initial key. And in subsequent iterations, all the bits are wrong.

If I use the test vector `00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f`, things go wrong much faster - I start getting wrong bits on the second iteration.

What's going on here? I notice Mr. Moser wrote in part *2b : 4* to `xor` with the first column of the *previous round key* - but there is no previous round for the initial key, so this confused me. Is this what I've done wrong?

For reference, [here are the test vectors.](http://www.samiam.org/key-schedule.html)

Comment: Can you produce a full, compiling, test case?  Fragments aren't very helpful here.

Comment: Happily! I've added a minimal version that compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a step.

```
xpndC ws = transpose [head ws, b, zipWith xor b c, last ws]
```

the fourth column should be the xor of the previous fourth column (which you've thrown away in the first pass) and the new third column.

The fact that `xor x x = 0` somehow contributed to this mistake being noticeable only at the fifth iteration.

---

Minor stylistic comments

Pattern matching on a fixed structure is less awkward than `(!!)`.

```
xpndC :: [[Word8]] -> [[Word8]]
xpndC [a,b,c,d] = [a, b, zipWith xor b c, d]
```

Also note that steps `2b4` and `3` are actually a scan. Roughly, it ends up looking like this (with the name `schedule_core` borrowed from your last link):

```
new = tail $ scanl (zipWith xor) (schedule_core (last old)) old
```

---

## Edit: Fix

The solution is essentially to *not* throw away the last column. You can, as a quick fix, inject it in an additional pass this way:

```
keys = f 16 $ f 8 $ f 4 $ f 2 $ f 1 key
 where
  f w n = xpndE (transpose n) . xpndC . xpndB . xpndA $ xpndD w n

xpndE n [a,b,c,_] = transpose [a,b,c,zipWith xor c (last n)]

xpndC = (...) {- remove transpose here -}
```

The `xpnd*` functions may be a bit too fine-grained, once you realize that the list is quite small. I would also factor `transpose` out, if you want to keep it at all.

```
keys = transpose $ f 16 $ f 8 $ f 4 $ f 2 $ f 1 $ transpose key
  where
    f rc [a, b, c, d] =
      let e = schedule rc d
          a' = zipWith xor a e
          b' = zipWith xor b a'
          c' = zipWith xor c b'
          d' = zipWith xor c c'
      in [a', b', c', d']  -- Here is where one may recognize `scanl` or a fold.
```

As for `schedule`, it's the function that takes the last column (`d` above, `last tW` below) and scrambles it (`e` above, `w'` below). You can extract it from your definition of `xpndD`:

```
xpndD rc ws = take 3 tW ++ [w']
 where
  w' = zipWith xor (map sub w) [rc, 0, 0, 0]
  tW = transpose ws
  w  = take 4 $ tail $ cycle $ last tW
```

We get (modulo a purely cosmetic rewriting `take 4 $ tail $ cycle d = tail d ++ [head d]`):

```
schedule rc d = zipWith xor (map sub $ tail d ++ [head d]) [rc, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on pattern matching... but could you elaborate on how I'm supposed to redefine `xpndC`, if I've already thrown away the column I'm supposed to `xor` the 4th column with? 

I would also love to use the `scanl`, but I can't figure out how to translate the C code for `schedule_core` into Haskell. I know it's asking a lot but I could I see these ideas in a bit more in context? I get the impression non-trivial refactoring is needed.

Comment: A fantastic answer - I especially appreciate the 'quick fix' in addition to the explanation of the more elegant scan. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it!

Comment: Wow, major kudos for digging into some fairly complex code and debugging it